# web / mobile based pdf signature with DocuSignAPI

Tags: javascript, docusignapi, sandbox

Working on a web and mobile application, for both of them I want the client be able to open a file for example a pdf on either web or mobile then sign the pdf.  I read taht DocuSignAPI has such thing available.

I talked to the DocuSignAPI contacts and then told me to post on stackoverflow since the community is quite big since he/she cannot give me an answer.

I know that there is a sandbox available but before taking all the time to test it out.  I want to know more, as I mentioned above would it work for web / mobile base to open the pdf at browser then DocuSignAPI is able to sign it then either save a copy locally then the user upload it again or something like that?

I went through the loan sample app but each of them were asking to fill out a form first instead of user able to open a file then place a signature or something.

Thanks in advance for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your use case is very standard for DocuSign API developers. We call what you're describing "embedded signing."

See the code example launcher in your favorite language, listed below.

After you download, configure it, and run it, look for example #1, "Embedded Signing." Try it from a mobile to see how it works.

Then ask additional questions here if you run into any issues.

C# -- https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core

PHP – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant

Java – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant

Node.js – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant

Python – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant

Ruby – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant

Curl (direct API) – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl